# Get Tried Paths for PHP's include

Tags: php

Is it in any way possible to tell PHP that I want to have a list of tried paths whenever `include` fails? The file is there, yet PHP is telling me the `include` failed.

Comment: It tries each path listed in the include_path setting until it succeeds, what else do you need to know?

Comment: Because the path *is* in the `include_path`, and at the very first place of it. And yet I have this problem.

Comment: @LambdaDusk What's the actual error coming from `include` then? File not found or what?

Comment: It's the Varien autoloader, but that one only includes the file after creating the filename from the class name. The class name is correct, the include_path has the path in it, yet I get the error that the .php was not found.

Comment: So basically, you're telling me that PHP does not have this feature that about any useful compiler/interpreter in the world has. Ok then.

Comment: @LambdaDusk Could you provide the full error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_include_path()](http://www.php.net/get_include_path) to find out what paths have been used by the `include`/`require` methods to source files.

It's a setting in `php.ini` (of course overridable by your application) that determines where these methods should look. They won't look anywhere else.

If you need these methods to look elsewhere, simply append another folder path with `PATH_SEPARATOR`, like so:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $newPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only paths it checks are the include paths.  You can just use [`get_include_path`](https://www.php.net/get_include_path).

```
 $dirs = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
```

---

More information on the include path setting [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).